# c# Panel with autoscroll - Srollbar position reset on a control focus

Tags: c#, winforms

This is for a windows form.

Panel has AutoScroll = True

I am adding panels dynamically to the main panel which end up exceeding the main panel display rectangle.
Then adding Labels, Combo Boxes, and Text Boxes to the added panels.

If I select a Combo Box or Text Box it resets the main panels scroll bar position to 0 and also the drop down menu for a Combo Box will be placed on the screen X,Y where it should be if the scrollbar had not reset.

I am thinking of saving the scroll position when a control is selected. After testing it seems the scroll position is not reset yet so I am able to capture it here. Then restoring the scroll position on some event of the panel I hope. **I am trying to find out exactly what event I would use to restore the scroll position.** I also hope that the drop down menu will be placed at the correct x,y when I do this.

A better solution would be to create a custom control based off the panel control and override an event possibly? This way I would not need to clutter up my project with saving the scroll position every time I use a scrolling panel.

Comment: It seems that if I select the control once it will jump to the top then if I select that same control again after scrolling down again the scrollbar position will not be reset.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem I was having here:
[Answer](http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/c-panel-resets-scroll-position-after-focus-is-lost-and-regained/)

```
public class CustomPanel : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
{
    protected override System.Drawing.Point ScrollToControl(System.Windows.Forms.Control activeControl)
    {
        // Returning the current location prevents the panel from
        // scrolling to the active control when the panel loses and regains focus
        return this.DisplayRectangle.Location;
    }
}
```

Comment: For future generations (and if link gets broken): 1. Subclass Panel 2. override ScrollToControl() to return this.DisplayRectangle.Location

Comment: For the faint of heart: _Subclassing_ doesn't involve more than: Paste the above code into your _Form.cs_ and change the two spots in the _Form.Designer.cs_ from `..System.Panel` to `CustomPanel`.

Comment: When using a TabPage instead of a Panel, the procedure is exactly the same, but you have to subtract 3 pixels from the DisplayRectangle.Location's X and Y values for the border of the TabControl.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, this works great except I had to adjust for the panel's padding at the bottom. Just an FYI to any others who may be seeing some offsets.

```
protected override System.Drawing.Point ScrollToControl(System.Windows.Forms.Control activeControl)
{
    Point retPt = DisplayRectangle.Location;
    retPt.Offset(new Point(-1*Padding.Left, -1*Padding.Bottom));

    return retPt;
}
```

Comment: This worked better for me than the other solution because it accounts for padding. The other solution was causing my clicks to cause a very slight scroll up.