# Autoscroll on panel keeps kicking to top

Tags: vb.net

I have autoscroll enabled on panel and it keeps kicking to top if i enable one of the numericupdown tools on top. I uploaded a gif to show it clearly : https://gph.is/g/4MgbYyL

Comment: Possible [Solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9317532/2330053).

Comment: Thanks but i can't seem to find how to translate it to visual basic language can you help me with that ?

Comment: Are you manipulating the Focus (or Validation events) on these NumericUpDown controls? This can happen if you re-set the focus on some condition. It also happens if you press TAB and move the Focus to a control in another container (setting the ActiveControl) and then TAB back (this is the standard behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks but i can't seem to find how to translate it to visual basic
>   language can you help me with that ? – Mustafa Tosun

[Solution by Untouchable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306975/c-sharp-panel-with-autoscroll-srollbar-position-reset-on-a-control-focus/9317532#9317532) Translated to VB.Net:

```
Public Class CustomPanel
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Panel

    Protected Overrides Function ScrollToControl(activeControl As Control) As Point
        Return Me.DisplayRectangle.Location
    End Function

End Class
```

Don't know if this will actually solve your problem, though.

Comment: Nope it didn't help unfortunately